# MySQL: sub query multiple columns

Tags: mysql, subquery, multiple-columns

I have tables called `orders` & `notifications`. When the admin updates any order status then it is stored in `notifications` table and `orders` table's `updated_at` value is updated (to be displayed on the top).

Here are my tables:

```
orders:
id, order_number, ..., updated_at

notifications:
id, order_id, order_status, remarks
```

On the `orders` page I need to show the order with the latest `order_status` & `remarks`.

```sql
SELECT
    `orders`.`token`,
    `orders`.`order_number`,
    `orders`.`order_date`, (
        SELECT SUM(`mrp` * `quantity`) FROM `order_items`
        WHERE `order_id` = `orders`.`id`
    ) AS `total`, (
        SELECT `order_status` FROM `notifications`
        WHERE `order_id` = `orders`.`id`
        ORDER BY `id` DESC
        LIMIT 0, 1
    ) AS `status`
FROM `orders`
WHERE `orders`.`company_id` = 1
AND `orders`.`user_id` = 5
GROUP BY `orders`.`id`
ORDER BY `orders`.`updated_at` DESC
```

The `sub-query` can return only 1 column. Is there a way to get the `order_stat` & `remarks` in single query. I mean without adding any other sub-query or hitting another query in the loop.?

Answer (score 0):

Single subquery can be in JOIN like this.

```
SELECT
    `orders`.`token`,
    `orders`.`order_number`,
    `orders`.`order_date`,
    (
        SELECT SUM(`mrp` * `quantity`)
        FROM `order_items`
        WHERE `order_id` = `orders`.`id`
    ) AS `total`,
    `notifications`.`order_status`,
    `notifications`.`remarks`,
FROM `orders`
LEFT JOIN `notifications` ON `notifications`.`id`=(SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `notifications` WHERE `order_id`=`orders`.`id`)
WHERE `orders`.`company_id` = 1
    AND `orders`.`user_id` = 5
GROUP BY `orders`.`id`
ORDER BY `orders`.`updated_at` DESC
```

But honestly I don't know if it performs better. I would recommend to debug both versions using `EXPLAIN`